# Missing Email for Sending without certain text in HTML in the Visual C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, wcf, email

I am writing this to ask very weird problem in the program.

Purpose of the program is to gather information and send email to users.

However, it does not send email without certain words or something in HTML code.

Please, refer to the below message.

> lstReport.Add(" This is a PCR Preparation Email. Please Refer to the below Contents. Thanks... ");

If we put this line in HTML code it will send E-mail. but without this line

It will not send E-mail, there is no error, no exception seems like blocking by server or firewall.

Please refer to below email setting.

```
private void SendMail(string fileName, StringBuilder message){

        MailMessage mail;
        SmtpClient client;
        mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(FromAddress);
        foreach (string to in ToAddress)
        {
            mail.To.Add(to);
        }
        mail.Subject = Subject + fileName;
        mail.Body = message.ToString();
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        client = new SmtpClient(MailServer);
        client.Send(mail);
    }
```

Please, explain to me if anyone knows about it.

Thanks in advance.

please refer to below body

```
lstReport.Add("<table><tr><td> This is a PCR Preparation Email. Please Refer to the below Contents. Thanks... </td></tr><tr><td></td></tr></table>"); 
lstReport.Add("<table border='0'><tr><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;>Number of Blots :");
lstReport.Add(Convert.ToString(blotCount) + "</td></tr><tr height=2><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family:Arial;>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;>Technician  :");
lstReport.Add(dtDiscrepancy.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString() + "&nbsp;</td></tr><tr height=2><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family:Arial;>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;>MM LotNumber  :");
lstReport.Add(dtDiscrepancy.Rows[0]["LotNumber"].ToString() + "&nbsp;</td></tr><tr height=2><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family:Arial;>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;>MM Volume  :");
lstReport.Add("<tr><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;>Please find below, the details of plates </td></tr> <tr><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;></td></tr><tr><td style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;>");
lstReport.Add("<table border=1 width=78% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width=13% style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;><b>PCRBlotName</b></td><td width=13% style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;><b>PCRPlateName</b></td><td width=13% style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;><b>DNABlotName</b></td><td width=13% style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;><b>DNAPlateName</b></td><td width=13% style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;><b>DNAVolume</b></td><td width=13% style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;><b>PrimerLocusGroup</b></td><td width=13% style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;><b>DNAMatch</b></td><td width=13% style=font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;><b>PrimerMatch</b></td></tr>");
lstReport.Add(Environment.NewLine);
lstReport.Add(tableHeader);
```

Comment: Please make sure your mail server allows you to use it. Ask the admin team to give a permission :)

Comment: post the full message body and change your question text: it is not clear when the message is sent and when not

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I think it's not because of permission because I can send e-mail if I put "This is a PCR Preparation Email. Please Refer to the below Contents. Thanks... " This message in the code.

Comment: Thank you Giammin I try to post but it couldn't because of HTML code format I will try to post it

Comment: `></table>"` you are ending / closing your Table tag in the first line. that should be closed at the line above the Environment.NewLine. also why not build your html table in a cleaner way inside of a Method or something. it's a bit messy and hard to follow in regards to Srolling

Comment: And HTML formatting should not prevent you from sending Email. perhaps you are not specifying the `smtp host and port` have you stepped thru the code..? if you are not sure please wrap the code around a `try{}catch{}` block

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice DJ KRAZE I already wrap try{ } catch {} in SendMail method but they didn't show any exception. I will double check smtphost and port ! but one thing that strange, sometime it's work sometimes it's not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should [Dispose](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using) your `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` after you have used it.

```
using (var mail = new MailMessage())
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient(MailServer))
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(FromAddress);
        foreach (string to in ToAddress)
        {
            mail.To.Add(to);
        }
        mail.Subject = Subject + fileName;
        mail.Body = message.ToString();
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.Send(mail); 
    }
}
```

Then remove `mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;` because it is useless and some server think it is spam.

**I could bet one hand that you are sending a malformed html in your Email body message.
Double check it for unclosed tags or unescaped chars.**

Use an application like [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/) as smtp server to see if the email are being sent.

Smtp server may block your email if you send too often or without a proper authentication.

There are many spam filters...

Comment: could u briefly explain to me how to dispose MailMessage and SmtpClient?